# What's wrong with this code? (JScrollPanel and JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

For some reason, when I run this code, my JFrame comes up as blank. I have been trying online tutorials for maybe an hour now, and I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding something.

Here is the code:

```
public class Application {

    public static JFrame f;
    public static JButton submit;
    public static JTextField unscramblee;
    public static String scrambledWord, possibleWords;
    public static JLabel possibleWordsDisplay;
    public static JPanel UI;
    public static JScrollPane scrollPane;

    Application() {
        f = new JFrame("test");
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        UI = new JPanel();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(UI);
        unscramblee = new JTextField("test");
        unscramblee.setBounds(240, 200, 400, 50);
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(240, 350, 400, 100);
        possibleWordsDisplay = new JLabel("possibleWordsDisplay - this is a display for words that are possible");
        possibleWordsDisplay.setBounds(240, 0, 200, 200);

        scrollPane.add(unscramblee);
        scrollPane.add(submit);
        scrollPane.add(possibleWordsDisplay);

        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(1280,720);
    }
}
```

I hope this is enough information to help. Thanks.

(If anyone is wondering why the setSize method comes after the pack method, it's because the JFrame keeps collapsing on itself when I run it. If you also know how to fix that please tell me! I'd be very thankful.)

Comment: I assume you want to add `unscramblee, submit, possibleWordsDisplay` to `UI` and not to `scrollPane`. It is vital to learn to use [layout managers](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+layout&oq=java+swing+layout&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l4j69i60l3.4175j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting bound manually is not a viable practice. 
Instead use the appropriate [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the desired layout. 
The following is [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)<sup>1</sup> (note the comments) :

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Application {

    Application() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("test");
        //f.setSize(1280,720); f.pack  should automatically set the size  
        f.setResizable(true);
        //f.setLayout(null); do not use null layout
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel UI = new JPanel();  // uses flowlayout by default
        //UI.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720); do not set bounds. that the job of the layout manager

        JTextField unscramblee = new JTextField("test", 10);
        //unscramblee.setBounds(240, 200, 400, 50);
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        //submit.setBounds(240, 350, 400, 100);
        JLabel possibleWordsDisplay = new JLabel("possibleWordsDisplay - this is a display for words that are possible");
        //possibleWordsDisplay.setBounds(240, 0, 200, 200);

        UI.add(unscramblee);
        UI.add(submit);
        UI.add(possibleWordsDisplay);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(UI);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane); //uses borderlayout by default 
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true); //make frame visible after construction is completed 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application();
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Always consider an mre when posting question or answers

Answer (score 0):

When creating a GUI, consider following the below design to start:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.start();

}

private void start() {
    frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    makeContent();

    frame.setSize(500, 130);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private void makeContent() {
    contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    makePanel();

}

private void makePanel() {
    JPanel ui = new JPanel();
    ui.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ui, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JLabel possibleWordsDisplay = new JLabel("possibleWordsDisplay - this is a display for words that are possible"); 
    ui.add(possibleWordsDisplay);

    JTextField unscramblee = new JTextField();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(unscramblee);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    ui.add(scroll);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    ui.add(submit);

    contentPane.add(ui, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

Comment: 1.Always consider [mre] when posting questions or answers 2. ContentPane uses `BorderLayout` by default  3. The requirement is for a panel with 3 components.

Comment: The code is still not mre. Please read the link provided. Most important: there is no need to set bounds when using a layout manager. The layout manager does it for you.